# Mock Location 213

Tags: android

i want change Location in all apps iam use that but dont work

```
     override fun onPlaceSelected(place: Place) {

            val latLng = place.latLng!!

            zoomOnMap(latLng)
            changeLocation(latLng)
            setMockLocation(latLng)
            Log.i("gk", "Place: ${place.latLng}")

        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
        private fun changeLocation(latLng: LatLng) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {

                return
            }
            val locationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext())
            locationProvider.setMockMode(true)
            val providerName = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER

            val mockLocation = Location(providerName)
            mockLocation.latitude = latLng.latitude
            mockLocation.longitude = latLng.longitude

            mockLocation.time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            mockLocation.accuracy = 1f
            mockLocation.elapsedRealtimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mockLocation.bearingAccuracyDegrees = 0.1f
                mockLocation.verticalAccuracyMeters = 0.1f
                mockLocation.speedAccuracyMetersPerSecond = 0.01f
            }

            locationProvider.setMockLocation(mockLocation)

        }
```

@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
fun setMockLocation(latLng: LatLng) {
val locationManager = requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager?
locationManager!!.addTestProvider(
LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, false, false,
false, false, true, true, true, 0, 5
)
locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true)
val mockLocation = Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
mockLocation.latitude = latLng.latitude // Sydney
mockLocation.longitude = latLng.longitude

```
            mockLocation.accuracy = 5f
            mockLocation.time = System.currentTimeMillis()
            mockLocation.elapsedRealtimeNanos = System.nanoTime()
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                mockLocation
            )
        }

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
    tools:ignore="MockLocation,ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).